# What's the easiest way to implement routes in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm having a hard time understanding how to implemente routes in vue.js using the official guide, is there a way to maybe streamline the process?

Comment: Please edit your question to show specifically what issue you're having. As written, this is too broad (and unclear): you mentioned you want to streamline the process, but it's unclear what you're referring to.

Comment: There are two main ways to implement routing in Vue: [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) (most of the work is client-side) and [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide) (most of the work is server-side). If you set up a project with `vue ui`, it gives you the option to add vue-router into your generated project automatically, if you're struggling with putting it in manually.

Comment: I have one day to implement vue.router, and I don't know if it's me but I'm finding it very hard to understand this paradigm, I came from java (Springboot framework) and php

Answer (score 4):

You can use Vue router library. Here, components is the folder where vue components are added. The variable "path" refers to the url route.

This is a sample router file I created.

```
     import Vue from "vue";
     import Router from "vue-router";

     Vue.use(Router);

     export default new Router({
       routes: [
       {
          path: "/",
          component: () => import("@/components/Login"),    
       },
       {
          path: "/home",
          name : "home",
          component: () => import("@/components/Home"),   
       },
     ]
    });
```

Please refer this document : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html

Also, import your router file into app initialisation.

```
 import router from "./router";

 new Vue({
   router,
   render: h => h(App)
 }).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: You should link the docs & the npm install command to add the package

Comment: Can I do it with html? like import("@/start.html")

Comment: You have to install vue-router library in your application. Refer: https://router.vuejs.org/.  Also, you can import your router file into your application initialisation. Please look at my edited answer